# Joining GIS chat room

Tags: feature-request, chat

I am trying to join the GIS Chat Room but they said that I should login to Stack Exchange.  Now I have logged in there but I am still not getting access to the chat of www.gis.stackexchange.com.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

This question arises from the confusing experience of clicking the [visit chat] button at the right of any question on the main site. Instead of ending up at [gis chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108/gis) one ends up at the [front end](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) for all chats across all stack exchange sites. And from there it's not immediately clear how to find the particular room you're interested in (hint: use the "filter rooms" text field).

This is something that's broken across all stack exchange sites.

I added the `feature-request` tag to the question for the SE developers to have a look at one their next sweep through. (I'm not sure if this is as effective of posting same on [MetaSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), lets find out. :-)