# Making the chat more visible?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, chat

### A proposed feature

After Vince suggested to a user who had a question that it could be treated as a [nice open discussion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357357/best-open-tool-library-for-simple-network-distance-calculations#comment584723_357357) on the chat, I tried to search for it on our main page.

I found only two occurrences of the word 'chat'. One of them being a featured element on the right (which might not last forever).  The other is at the really [bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJdMj.jpg) (<- link to a screenshot of the home page) of the page, hidden in the middle of some other small textual elements. It is also available with a two-clicks action by the "A list of the 175 Stack Exchange sites" button. Newcomers have to guess it's hidden there.

I would therefore suggest that the chat is given more prominence, for example with a 1-click direct access at the top of the home page, or close to the personal icons, for example before the inbox:

[image: Chat enhanced visibility]

I hope our community is able to modify this kind of feature, but I can understand if we depend on decisions of others (understand by this, 'external' people from the GIS community).

### Linked discussion

[need guidance in joining the gis chat room](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223/need-guidance-in-joining-the-gis-chat-room)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not something in the SE user interface that we at GIS can modify, and so your feature request is best posted at the network-wide Meta Stack Exchange.

I thought I would quickly find a feature request (probably declined) there but all I've found so far is:

- [Better advertising for the chat rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331310/215590)

In the meantime we have this Meta GIS SE Q&A to help our users find the GIS Chat Rooms:

- [Where are GIS Chat Rooms?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/678/where-are-gis-chat-rooms)

I am not a great fan of chat rooms (here or elsewhere) but as a moderator I feel obliged to look in on ours frequently.  Of the three main components of GIS SE I think it is significantly less important than the other two and its lack of prominence suggests to me that the Stack Overflow company may hold similar views.  This is where I think the GIS Chat Room fits alongside the Main and Meta sites:

1. [Main site of GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/) - is for focused Q&A and frequently moderated by many GIS SE users (including its eight elected moderators)
2. [Meta site of GIS SE](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/) - is for discussion and focused Q&A about how the Main site works, and occasionally moderated by a much smaller number of GIS SE users (including its eight elected moderators)
3. [GIS Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis) - is for anything you wish to ask or discuss about GIS, and is rarely/never moderated.  If anyone has trouble framing a question for focused Q&A this is the place to post it and you may find someone willing to help you work through it.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a quick link to Chat, from the hamburger menu at top-right.  From this menu you get quick access to Main, Meta, Help, and Chat, plus other SE communities you are active in.

[image]

Comment: That's the "two-clicks action" s.k. wrote about. And it is rather hidden, yes.

Comment: @Erik Yes it is the two-click action from the Question, however I would argue against it being "rather hidden" - I would think that typically a standard webpage menu would be one of the first places to look for something (and therefore not really "hidden"), but perhaps that's just me.